# How is work Wifi of lenovo laptop Manualy?

Tags: windows-7

I have a Lenovo computer and I am facing issues regarding WiFi.

When I start WiFi and try to connect to a network, the WiFi signal always shows a cross over it, but when I put my laptop in sleep mode and then start again then its WiFi starts automatically.

Comment: it's drivers. Most laptops need to be downgraded windows or need new drivers, what probably don't exist

Comment: Can you provide the wireless card make and model (a hardware ID would be very useful). There should be absolutely no need to downgrade your OS.

Comment: https://superuser.com/users/88534/catalyst ..Thanks I have applied these things. There have no drivers issues.... I think i have to replace older drivers to newly...

Answer (score 0):

https://superuser.com/users/321172/kinnectus
I am not getting proper answer another one thing more happening in the laptop that CTRL+X and CTRL+S is not working but individually all keys are working properly. What should i have to do for command keys.

All driver are ok related to keyboard.